# My variable is undefined in my render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a variable that I need in my React class.

But when I define it in the `construtor`, it becomes undefined when I try to use it in the `render()` method.

How can I make it so that my variable is available in the `render()` method?

Here is what I have:

```
export default class GameConsole extends React.PureComponent {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var domainUrl = window.location.origin;
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <GameControl
               init={{
                  masterUrl = domainUrl;
```

Comment: Just define it within the `render` method.

Comment: `domainUrl` is local to the `constructor` function. There's no real reason to put it in the ctor; you can access `window` inside `render`. You could set `this.domainUrl` (like in any other class) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the value to the component's [local state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class):

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    domainUrl: window.location.origin,
  };
}

render() {
  // Can access it on `this.state` inside render
  this.state.domainUrl;
}
```

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to put it in `state` rather than an instance variable or accessing `window` directly in `render`? To me it seems like `state` is for a different purpose than non-state/-prop data.

Comment: I suggested to use state to prevent a future question of, "I did this.domainUrl = X; but the value didn't change on the screen." There's no extra cost of using `state` in this case because the value of `domainUrl` never changes. If you know the limitations of not using state, then you can 100% skip it like you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Write this:

```
export default class GameConsole extends React.PureComponent {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        
}


render() {

var domainUrl = window.location.origin;
    return (
        <div>
            <GameControl
               init={{
                  masterUrl = domainUrl;
```